# Having problems creating email-only signup in Devise and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am currently working on setting up a project based around the [tutorial on Devise labeled Email only signup](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Email-only-sign-up) and seem to be encountering one specific error which I cannot work around. I have got the plugin to do everything except step 3 where it fails to find the custom method I have added called `confirm`. I have already told Devise to use

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:confirmations => 'confirmations'}
```

for my users plugin, but it is ignoring my controller.

I have a controller called confirmations_controller.rb and it contains the following code:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.find_by_confirmation_token(params[:confirmation_token])
    super if resource.confirmed? 
  end

  def confirm
    self.resource = resource_class.find_by_confirmation_token(params[resource_name][:confirmation_token])
    if resource.update_attributes(params[resource_name].except(:confirmation_token)) && resource.password_match?
      self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[resource_name][:confirmation_token])
      set_flash_message :notice, :confirmed
      sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
    else
      render :action => "show"
  end
end
```

The exact error is:

```
undefined method `confirmed?' for #<User:0x425f130>
```

I am using rails version 3.2.9 and devise version 2.2.1

I am just learning rails and ruby so I really hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Did you add :confirmable to the User class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is about the `confirmed?` method being not defined. The custom method you added is `confirm`

The `confirmed?` method is added by the [`confirmable` module of device](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable#confirmed%3F-instance_method)

As Jesse mentioned in the comment above, enable the 'confirmable' module for the User class.

Example User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise ..., :confirmable, ...

  ...

end
```

Comment: Thank you, I did miss this, however in order to completely solve the issue I had to follow the guide here to fix the next error which arose: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users